# Consolidate all array values with serial keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working on a Laravel app where the user can curate posted data with few options.
So whenever user make a post he has given option to add category for that and fill more details depending on that category. On submit post data get saved with it's category id( i am saving this category and it's curated values to other table by putting it's id to post table).

array after posting data is like:

```
            Array
    (
  [title] => this is data 
   [subhead] => this is data this is data this is data this is data 
   [htmlcontent] => this is data&nbsp;this is data&nbsp;this is data&nbsp;this is data&nbsp;this is data&nbsp;this is data&nbsp;
  [category] => story
   [author] => Array
    (
        [0] => author 1
        [1] => author 2
    )

[facts] => Array
    (
        [0] => facts
    )

[inspiration] => Array
    (
        [0] => insp1 
        [1] => insp2
    )

[tags] => Array
    (
        [0] => tag
    )

[refrence] => Array
    (
        [0] => ref1
        [1] => ref2
        [2] => ref3
    )
```

)

Now according to my situation, user can edit every single option, like he can edit author 1,2  and save it. for this i have to save every single value with identifier. Hence using author1 ,author2 to make it unique.

I have curated an option array for a post and it looks like this:

```
  Array ( [_id]       => 537ded7e8b5c880c1f000029
          [category]  => story 
          [author1]   => Anil Sharma 
          [author2]   => Tester 
          [citaion1]  => cited 
          [citaion2]  => cited2
          [tags]      => tag1,tag2,tag3
          [refrence1] => facebook.com
          [refrence2] => twitter
        )
```

And on the frontend I have to show the data like this:

```
   Expected Output
        category    story 
        author      Anil Sharma 
                    Tester 
        citaion     cited 
                    cited2
        tags        tag1,tag2,tag3
        refrence    facebook.com
                    twitter    


   Current Output

        category    story 
        author1      Anil Sharma 
        author2     Tester 
        citaion1     cited 
        citaion2     cited2
        tags        tag1,tag2,tag3
        refrence1    facebook.com
        refrence2    twitter
```

---

```
 HTML to show this :
    @foreach($category as $key => $value)
            <li>
             <label class="detailhead">{{$key}}</label>
             <p class="inlineedit" data-type="textarea" data-pk="{{$data->id}}" data-placement="left" data-url="{{URL::to('/')}}/ajax/post" data-title="Enter {{$key}}" id="{{$key}}_hoot">{{$value}}
             </p>

  </li>

  @endif
```

I can't make any change to key's name because they are the identifier for that part.On their value click user can edit the part with jQuery UI editables. User can curate any option and i have to save it accordingly. So what would be the best way to achieve this. should i make or filter array part in view section, but the thing I need to keep in mind is that whenever I am showing this thing into view I have to keep `id="{{$key}}"` unique in the tag. With its help, I am saving that particular curated part.

So what would be the best way for me to achieve this?

Comment: Is the array fixed like that? Or is it variable? i.e. is there always 2x citations, 2x author, 2x reference in the array?

Comment: You could use some regex on the backend to alter the array in such a way that you'll bunch together all values with keys that end with a number, then you pass that array to the frontend.

Comment: it's not fixed .it 's dynamic there can be more citation, author, or refrences, like author 1, 2, 3. or citation1,2,3 @TheShiftExchange

Comment: How is the inital array generated? Can you change that to a better structure to make your life easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this (I've stripped the html css stuff out to make it easier to read):

```
<?php $previousKey = null; ?>
@foreach($category as $key => $value)
      <li>
          @if ((substr($key, 0, -1) != substr($previousKey, 0, -1))
              <label class="detailhead">{{ $key }}</label>
          @endif
          <p>{{$value}}</p>
      </li>
      <?php $previousKey = $key; ?>
@endif
```

Its not the cleanest solution - you could refactor it to improve the code - but you get the idea. Basically it just compares the current key to the previous one with the number. So `citation1` and `citation2` would match, but only print the first citation key name.

How is the initial array generated? Can you change that to a better structure to make your life easier?

Comment: no it doesn't work. whenever i try to use this solution my browser(chrome) says no data received

Comment: might be due to the shorttags - I fixed them in my answer - try again?

Comment: i don't think so , their must be some other issue ,already checked it before.

Comment: Well my code is not very different from yours? Just remove sections until you see the error? Do you have debug turned on? But on my computer this code solves your question.

Comment: Maybe put the html/css stuff back in - perhaps jQuery is waiting to receive it?

Comment: no there was extra parenthesis. Code is running but nothing happens

Comment: it's working. thanx for help. But i think refactoring it would be to make an array with respective  key before sending it to view would be somehow cleaner solution .